# Subresource and path variable conflicts in REST?

Tags: rest, jersey, jax-rs

Is it considered bad practice to design a REST API that may have an ambiguity in the path resolution?  For example:

```
GET /animals/{id}   // Returns the animal with the given ID
GET /animals/dogs   // Returns all animals of type dog
```

Ok, that's contrived, because you would actually just do `GET /dogs`, but hopefully it illustrates what I mean.  From a path resolution standpoint, it seems like you wouldn't know whether you were looking for an animal with `id="dogs"` or just all the `dogs`

Specifically, I'm interested in whether Jersey would have any trouble resolving this.  What if you knew the `id` to be an integer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> "Specifically, I'm interested in whether Jersey would have any trouble resolving this"

No this would not be a problem. If you look at [the JAX-RS spec § 3.7.2](https://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.1/spec/spec.html), you'll see the algorithm for matching requests to resource methods.

> [*E* is the set of matching methods]...
>
> Sort *E* using the number of literal characters in each member as the primary key (descending order), the number of capturing groups as a secondary key (descending order) and the number of capturing groups with non-default regular expressions (i.e. not ‘([^ /]+?)’) as the tertiary key (descending order)

So basically it's saying that the number of literal characters is the primary key of which to sort by (note that it is short circuiting; you win the primary, you win). So for example if a request goes to `/animals/cat`, `@Path("/animals/dogs")` would obviously not be in the set, so we don't need to worry about it. But if the request is to `/animals/dogs`, then both methods would be in the set. The set is then sorted by the number of literal characters. Since `@Path("/animals/dogs")` has more literal characters than `@Path("/animals/")`, the former wins. The capturing group `{id}` doesn't count towards literal characters.

> "What if you knew the id to be an integer?"

The capture group allows for regex. So you can use `@Path("/animals/{id: \\d+}")`. Anything not numbers will not pass and lead to a 404, unless of course it is `/animals/dogs`.